# Flow and Diffeomorphisims

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Let $M \subset R^n$ be open, $f \in C^1 (M, R^n)$, and $\Phi$ be the
>   flow associated to $x' = f(x)$. Show that $\Phi (k, ·) (k ∈ Z)$ is the
>   discrete flow associated to the diffeomorpism $F = \Phi(1, ·)$. Does
>   every diffeomorphism $F$ arise in such a way?

I figured out the first part since it follows directly as $\Phi (k, .) = \Phi^k (1, .)$ but I am still trying in the second part. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Does M have to be connected?

Comment: Another hint: is there any way to embed $\overline{x} = -\frac{1}{2}x$ as a time-1 map of some flow on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Evgeny Can you be more explicit?

Comment: I don't know how to be more explicit without giving the full answer :) but the answer is -- no, not every diffeomorphism can be obtained as $F = \Phi(1, \cdot)$. Time-1 maps (that's another term for the procedure described in your question) have some specific properties; for example, they preserve orientation